# Ajax not working on ASP .NET after publishing to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

So last night i made a small web app with ASP .NET MVC and used some ajax on the views with partial views so i didn't have to make a whole bunch of different views that would should almost the same thing. Everything worked well on my local machine and then i published it to azure web apps but when i open the URL the ajax methods weren't working.
Do i have to do something on the azure platform to make the AJAX work? I'm new to the azure part
I went to the api section but i didn't see anything to add AJAX.

Comment: Did you changed your local urls to point to the azure site url in ajax calls?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Did you publish necessary script files to the Azure Environment? Is there any error on the console when trying to execute AJAX methods?

Comment: i have this one when i open the website `GET https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` and this one when i exceute one ajax method  `jquery.min.js:2 GET https://cantinhodochurrasco.azurewebsites.net/Home/Entradas?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1590350046878 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: If your ajax urls are pointing to Azure and still comes the error means, the error comes from server side code. Before debugging server side, check, web.config is correct. Such as check connection strings to databases are correct, wcf addresses are correct and not using local addresses if any. If they are ok, that means you need to debug somehow using remote debugging.